# Rapheal js image tiled

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I tried to display image node using Raphael library using following code.

```
var _in=paper.image("/irims/wms/image/"+img,x,y,_size,_size);
```

This code is working well in IE9, Chrome, FF. 
By the way in IE8 and IE7 the image sometimes tiled. 
I tried to fix this using image attribute as follows but it was 
useless. 
_in.attr({"background-repeat":"no-repeat"});

I was wondering weather this is known issue or not. 
Does Raphael fully support IE8 and IE7? 
My Rapheal version is 2.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue. I've seen lots of posts about it. In Raphael 2.1.2, I had to modify a few lines around line 7233 to fix the issue:

```
if (fillpos) {
  c = compensation(deg, m.x(fillpos[0], fillpos[1]), m.y(fillpos[0], fillpos[1]));
  //  ORIGINAL LINE
  //  fill.position = c.dx * y + S + c.dy * y;

  //  NEW LINE
  fill.position = ((c.dx * y) + 1) + S + ((c.dy * y) + 1);
}
if (_.fillsize) {
  //  ORIGINAL LINE
  //  fill.size = _.fillsize[0] * abs(sx) + S + _.fillsize[1] * abs(sy);

  //  NEW LINE
  fill.size = _.fillsize[0] * abs(sx) / 1.34 + "pt" + S + _.fillsize[1] * abs(sy) / 1.34 + "pt";
}
```

I hope that helps. Took me forever to fix this issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, this did not do it for me, editing those lines did nothing. How ever what worked for me was not setting the the view box, that seemed to fix the IE8 Image tiling issue.